# With TSQL, how do I create a record in Table2 using GUID from existing record in Table1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table1 contains Work Orders and Table2 contains Installers. I would like to insert a record into Table2 for Work Order 3906 in Table1 using unique identifier for that Work Order such that Table1GUID = Table2GUID . I'll worry about populating the new record later (all columns in Table2 can be blank for now except GUID which must be identical to corresponding GUID from Table1). Records for Table1 and Table2 are one to one.

This is NOT working: (0 row(s) affected)

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Table2GUID)
SELECT Table1GUID FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.WOnumber = '3906'
```

This doesn't work either:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Table2GUID)
SELECT Table1GUID FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2GUID = Table1GUID
WHERE Table1.WOnumber = '3906'
```

Comment: Take the Inserts away and see if you get a result first..        SELECT t1.Table1GUID From Table1 t1 WHERE t1.WOnumber = '3906'         If you get a result, check your required fields in Table2.  If you don't, then make sure 3906 actually exists.

Comment: Is you `WOnumber` a text field? does it have any trailing whitespaces or leading 0's?

Comment: I'm going to repost the question. I discovered that Table1GUID is blank for work order 3906 because there is no corresponding record in Table2. So what I actually need to do is create a NEWID() for Table1GUID and create a new record in Table2 where Table1GUID = Table2GUID